# Detecting small AC current signal generated by phototransistor

Tags: circuit-design, filter, phototransistor, high-pass-filter, photosensor

I'm trying to detect a small AC signal (~10kHz) generated by a phototransistor on a magnitude of 10nA~1uA using the following circuit by converting the signal to voltage signal first and then filter it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF6tHj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, environmental light generates a constant offset of approximately 50uA, which is much greater than my signal. This means that if need to convert the current signal to voltage signal first before filtering, assuming I power the amplifier with a 5V voltage source, **R** needs to be smaller than 100K Ohm in order to prevent saturation of the amplifier. As a result, the voltage signal would be merely 1~100mV, which is too small for accurate detection due to noise issues. If the 50uA background could be filtered out, I can use a larger R to convert current signal to a larger voltage signal.

In theory, some form of high-pass filter should solve the problem, but I have no idea how to apply a high-pass filter that operates directly on the current signal.

Any hint would be much appreciated! thanks!

Note: phototransistor's collector should be fixed at 0V.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You write phototransistor but your schematic shows a photodiode. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, a schematic editor will open.

Comment: @winny Thanks for your kind reminder! I've edited my post, however, I cannot find phototransistors in the circuitlab.

Comment: I may remember wrong, but can you set the base of an NPN to photo input?

Comment: @winny my phototransistor only provides two pins, a collector, and an emitter. the base is tied internally to the cathode of a photodiode.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m trying to help you show in CircuitLab :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @analogsystemsrf, I designed and verified a circuit which can serve this purpose well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSwSBK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key here is to design a stable, second order LPF on the feedback loop. Filters of 3+ orders would possibly cause oscillation so this is the best I could think of. Here current goes in from **I_in** pin, and the AC voltage goes out at **V_out** whild DC voltage can be obtained at **V_FB**.

Hopefully this could be useful for further viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Sunlight can be removed, with a low_pass feedback.

- Connect a series R + R network from output back to Vin-.
- these new resistors are in parallel with your current_to_voltage Resistor
- we need a very slow time constant, so add 1uF capacitor at midpoint of the 2 new series resistors
- make both the new resistors of value 1MegOhm.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, I get your point but do you mean that the feedback part should be something like this?

---R---C---R--- in paralell with --------R---------

Comment: I suppose this is a high-pass filter instead? it has lower Z on higher frequency. But your point is helpful, I would check if there's any other way to use another amplifier to generate a LPF on the feedback loop.